# What do you call this nose shape?

Tags: character-development, description

What would you call this nose shape?  I'm describing a southern Chinese character (not this guy). Snub or button-nose gets way overused and is not entirely accurate in this case.

EDIT:
The character is the protagonist's and narrator's best friend, so a likeable and sympathetic character. His physical description is not like a detective novel but like in literary fiction, as a visual description that is developed over time.
[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to know mood and context. Is your reader supposed to like this person, dislike him, or be neutral towards him? Are you just adding a touch of visual color or are you spending time developing a real picture of his face?

Comment: I'm with Ted. Physical descriptions out of context are like expo-dumps, or worse 'Chekov's Phrenology'…. Clinical descriptions act as 'filter words' between the reader and subject – we 'view' that person externally (like the cliché of male writers over-describing female bodies, it is intentionally objectifying). Race-descriptions don't exist in a vacuum. Impossible to read some as 'neutral'. If you tell me an arbitrary physical trait, I'll assume it is unusual *for the protagonist* (informs me on their prejudice). If it's not clearly Protag's voice, it becomes the author's.

Comment: I'm describing everybody in the novel.  Not like in a detective novel, but in bits and pieces here as need. This person is the protagonist/narrator's best friend.

Comment: @TedWrigley thanks. i've edited the answer to clarify.

Comment: This question is a vampire. I'd delete it if I could.

Comment: Honestly, we describe people's facial characteristics all the time. When I see people down voting a request for description of a non-European character, I really have to wonder.

Answer (score 2):

Some fun ways to describe a flat nose like this would include:

- **Aquiline** (comes with a connotation of being flat but pronounced)
- **Cauliflower** (implies a nose that is wide and flat)
- **Squashed** (connotates a very flat nose)
- **Wedge-shaped**
- **"Roman" or "Grecian"** (connotates a nose that is statue-like, flat, sculpturesque)
- **Funnel-shaped** (implies flat with large nostrils)

Here's a handy diagram of different nose types that I scrounged up, too:

[image: Diagram of various nose shapes]

Comment: Have to disagree with you on "Aquiline" and "Roman". These noses are beak-like, the very opposite of the nose depicted.